# Flush all cache in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel

Is there a way to flush all cache in Laravel 4? I'm using *file* for caching. I read on the docs that you can use `Cache::forget('key')` , but what if I need to delete all the cache?

An artisan command can also be useful, I think there's an issue on the repo, but not sure if it's implemented yet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 96, accepted):

If you run `php artisan list` then you can find all the commands available for `artisan`, anyways, there is a command to clear the `cache` and it's

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

Also, you can use

```
foreach (Cache::getMemory() as $cacheKey => $cacheValue)
{

    Cache::forget($cacheKey);
}
```

**Update:**

```
Cache::flush();
```

Comment: as of the time I'm writing this you can use Cache::flush() regardless of driver you are using. See the [Laravel API Cache](http://laravel.com/api/namespace-Illuminate.Cache.html) for this.

Comment: php artisan cache:clear might not always work in case of FileStore cache as the user who is executing the artisan command might not have write permissions to the cache files/directories. Usually the cached files are created by the webserver user who is not necessarily the same you use to run artisan.

Comment: Thanks @anonymous, I'll remember your advice and I'm really glad that you mentioned you downvoted because often some folks down votes anonymously and makes me confused. :-)

Answer (score 7):

`Illuminate\Cache\FileStore` has the function `flush`, so you can use:

```
Cache::flush();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use,

```
use Doctrine\Common\Cache\CacheProvider as DoctrineCache;

DoctrineCache::flushAll();
```

to flush all cache.

Comment: It's available in vendor/doctrine/cache/lib/Doctrine/Common/Cache/CacheProvider.php